# Fluent NHibernate JoinedSubClass is obsolete

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapping, joined-subclass

I wonder about something. I'm sitting here with a solution there I have 1 superclass that has 2 subclasses and I'm currently mapping this using JoinedSubClass, but I get that this method is obsolete, and says that I should ClassMap and SubClassMap, but if I do this the AutoMapping does not work, and I don't want that. Is there any workaround for this?

Here's the hierarchy:

```
public class Tag : Entity
{

public virtual string Name {get;set;}
public virtual User User {get;set;}

}

public class RespondentTag : Tag
{
    public virtual IList<Respondent> Respondents {get;set;}
}


public class ArchiveTag : Tag
{
    public virtual IList<Survey> Surveys {get;set;}
}
```

As you probably figured out I want this to be a table per hierarchy-mapping with subclasses with lists that are Many-To-Many. Like a table 'Tag', then Tag_Respondent and Tag_Archive (for many-to-many relationship).

Here's the mapping that I'm currently using:

```
public class TagMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Tag>
{
  public void Override(AutoMapping<Tag> mapping)
  { 
     //This is obsolete
     mapping.JoinedSubClass("RespondentTagId", RespondentTagMap.AsJoinedSubClass());
     mapping.JoinedSubClass("ArchiveTagId", ArchiveTagMap.AsJoinedSubClass());

  }
}

public class RespondentTagMap
{
    public static Action<JoinedSubClassPart<RespondentTag>> AsJoinedSubClass()
    {
     return part =>

        part.HasManyToMany(x => x.RespondentList)
           .Cascade
           .SaveUpdate()
           .Inverse()
           .Table("Tag_Respondent");

    }
}


public class ArchiveTagMap
{
    public static Action<JoinedSubClassPart<ArchiveTag>> AsJoinedSubClass()
    {
     return part =>

        part.HasManyToMany(x => x.Surveys)
           .Cascade
           .SaveUpdate()
           .Inverse()
           .Table("Tag_Archive");

    }
}
```

Does anyone know about a workaround or another solution for solving this? (Without disabling automapping)

Any answers will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm running into similar issues trying to get a mixed table-per-subclass and table-per-class-hierarchy working.

Comment: are you still having this problem? Which version of FNH did you use?

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding your objective, but I'll take a stab at this since I have similar inheritance in my project (though I use a table-per-base-class pattern with a discriminator column).

I believe you can accomplish what you're looking to do by having FNH ignore your `Tag` base class, then overriding the mapping on your `RespondentTag` and `ArchiveTag` objects to implement the many-to-many relationship. So in your FNH configuration, you'd specify an argument to your mappings call of:

```
m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<SomeObjectInMyAssembly>(new MyAutoMapConfig()) // Assuming you're using a config class
    .IgnoreBase(typeof(Entity))
    .IgnoreBase(typeof(Tag))
    .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<SomeOverrideClass>());
```

Then you'd have to set up overrides in whatever assembly you're storing them. You'd have something like this:

```
public class RespondentTagOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<RespondentTag>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<RespondentTag> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.RespondentList)
            .Cascade
            .SaveUpdate()
            .Inverse()
            .Table("Tag_Respondent"); // Not sure if the table call works in the override...you may have to use a convention for this
    }
}
```

Same for the `ArchiveTag` object.

That's similar to what I do in my inheritance scheme, though as I mentioned, in my automap config class I override the `IsDiscriminated` method to indicate that my objects are table-per-base-class and discriminated.